# Save the directory one above the current one in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, directory

Let's say I am working in the directory:

/home/username/Matlab/

I want to save (in a script) the directory one above the one I am working in (to use it later in the script), so:

```
newdir='home/username';
```

But I am working in different computers, so the 'username' changes, thus I want to do it automatically, such as save "newdir" as "one above the current directory".

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `..` syntax:

```
newdir="..";
```

Comment: Oh, that was so simple. Thanks a lot!